# Unexpected error in jabref 4.1 with java

Tags: java, installation, latex, version

yesterday I updated my jabref 4.0 to the lastest version, 4.1. However, when I open it appears this window:

[image]

I went to the java webpage and downloaded the Version 8 Update 151 available there, which I thought that could fix the error, but it didn't happen.

There are something else that I can do to fix it?

Comment: What's your OS? How did you install the new Java version?

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam hi, I'm using windows 10 pro. I uninstall java using IObit Uninstaller and then downloaded and installed java again

Comment: Try to run `java -version` in a command prompt. What's the output?

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam this is the result `C:\Users\usuario>java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)`

Comment: How did you originally installed the jabref? Was that the Windows installer or the runnable JAR?

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam if helps, I founded something in the jabref discussions, however still appearing the error [link](http://discourse.jabref.org/t/java-error-on-jabref/974/3)

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam I think that I installed jabref via windows installer

Comment: Can you also tell me the output of `echo $JAVA_HOME` command on a command prompt?

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam `C:\Users\usuario>echo $JAVA_HOME
$JAVA_HOME`

Comment: oops. sorry. I forgot you're on windows. it should be `echo %JAVA_HOME%`

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam is it correct? `C:\Users\usuario>echo %JAVA_HOME%
%JAVA_HOME%`

Comment: In which folder did you install Java? also did you install jre or jdk?

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam The path of the java folder is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java`. Inside this folder are another folder named `jre1.8.0_151`

Answer (score 0):

First of all re-install your JRE in a folder without any blank space in its name. Then if for example you install it into a folder like `C:\jre`, update your PATH environment variable and add `C:\jre\bin` to the very beginning of your path so that it would be the first folder that Windows would search to find the `java.exe` in your file system. By doing so it would be guaranteed that the version you're expecting would be used by "jabref".